# Помогите,пожалуйста, составить запрос

Tags: sql

У меня есть две таблицы, в одной написаны все пользователи, а в другой все звонки пользователей. Мне нужно вытащить все звонки определенных пользователей, т.е. из таблицы пользователей тех `id`, у которых `p.id = 12345`, а из таблицы звонков - поле цена, где `user_id=p.id`. Делается через `INNER JOIN`, но я не могу составить правильный запрос. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: [Может эта статья прояснит и поможет?](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html)

Answer (score 2):

Так?

```
SELECT users.id, calls.price FROM users 
INNER JOIN calls ON (users.id = calls.user_id) 
WHERE users.id = 12345
```

[Посмотреть на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d2978/6/0)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, вот я как раз не могу никак придумать, у меня в таблице users есть поле Id  это user_id будет в таблице call,так же в строке есть ещё поле user_id, куда пишется id партнера, т.е. нужно добавить условие, чтобы он искал в таблице call только те user_id, где в таблице user строка id содержит user_id = 12345. Скорее всего это очень непонятно, простите(

Comment: Вот пример строки из таблицы user http://joxi.ru/Y2LE5wYSnwJ1zA в таблице call выборка будет идти по user_id, это столбец id таблицы user

Comment: тогда просто нужно в `WHERE` заменить `users.id` на `users.user_id`

Comment: Спасибо, работает))